# Heroku returns "Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available" on starting Strapi CMS

Tags: heroku, strapi, heroku-cli

I am trying to deploy Strapi on Heroku

But it does not work. I get this log

```
2020-05-27T15:04:05.012958+00:00 app[web.1]: > strapi-oskogen-mongodb@0.1.0 start /app
2020-05-27T15:04:05.012959+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2020-05-27T15:04:05.012960+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-05-27T15:04:08.188595+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:23) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'count' of module exports inside circular dependency
2020-05-27T15:04:08.188639+00:00 app[web.1]: (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
2020-05-27T15:04:08.189164+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:23) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'findOne' of module exports inside circular dependency
2020-05-27T15:04:08.189299+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:23) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'remove' of module exports inside circular dependency
2020-05-27T15:04:08.189381+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:23) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'updateOne' of module exports inside circular dependency
2020-05-27T15:04:12.308848+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-27T15:04:12.308Z] error Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available 52.54.48.43:31639
2020-05-27T15:04:12.308857+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1296:21)
2020-05-27T15:04:12.308858+00:00 app[web.1]:     at listenInCluster (net.js:1361:12)
2020-05-27T15:04:12.308859+00:00 app[web.1]:     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (net.js:1498:7)
2020-05-27T15:04:12.308859+00:00 app[web.1]:     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:68:8)
2020-05-27T15:04:22.927720+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
```

I use MongoDB on Atlas. It works well on localhost both dev and prod environment.

My production files:

**server.js**

[image]

**database.js**

[image]

**response.js**

[image]

**app settings**

[image]

Where did I miss something?

Comment: did you solve it? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: Hi @Touha I have just answered to my question. :)

Answer (score 1):

Which is the value of `process.env.HOST`. For some reason different from `0.0.0.0` (just a shot in the dark - https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/migration-guide/migration-guide-beta.19-to-beta.19.4.html#listened-host-changed)

Answer (score 1):

I had to change server.js file (port 443):

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  host: env('HOST', '0.0.0.0'),
  port: env.int('PORT', 443),
  admin: {
    auth: {
      secret: env('ADMIN_JWT_SECRET'),
    },
  },
});
```

My database.js file:

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  defaultConnection: "default",
  connections: {
    default: {
      connector: "mongoose",
      settings: {
        uri: env("DATABASE_URI"),
        ssl: { rejectUnauthorized: false }
      },
      options: {
        ssl: true,
        authenticationDatabase: "",
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        pool: {
          min: 0,
          max: 10,
          idleTimeoutMillis: 30000,
          createTimeoutMillis: 30000,
          acquireTimeoutMillis: 30000
        }
      },
    },
  },
});
```

I hope it will help to somebody who has the same problem :-)

Comment: I don't understand how this could have solved your issue. Heroku will always define the PORT env var based on the port that has been chosen for your app (the port `31639` if I look at the error you got). It means that if you define your host with `env.int('PORT', 443)`, the PORT env var defined by Heroku will be used, not 443. What probably solved it is the fact that your host is now an integer but it used to be a string.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's what @Rochadsouza meant, but I got the same error and what finally solved the issue in my case was to set the host to `0.0.0.0`. For some reasons, the host cannot be the app url, it needs to allow all hosts on Heroku. I was setting the host in `server.js` using `env('HOST', '0.0.0.0')` but had the `HOST` env var set to my app url on Heroku...

Hope it saves some time to others facing the same error.